# exotic compact group

Tags: haar-measure, measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be compact (and Hausdorff) group, $\mu$ be Haar measure on $G$. Is it always true that $(G,\mu)$ is a standard probability space (Lebesgue-Rokhlin space)? It is so if (a priori not iff) the topology of $G$ is metrizable, but this is probably not necessary.

Comment: Well, some silly counter-examples: A finite group.  Or $\{0,1\}^I$ for some very, very large set $I$.

Comment: well, finite does not count, I had to mention it
the second example is ok, thank you